# Change liferay-ui:input-localized XML with javascript

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-7

I have the following tag in my view.jsp:

```
<liferay-ui:input-localized id="message" name="message" xml="" />
```

And I know that I can set a XML and have a default value on my input localized. My problem is that I want to change this attribute with javascript. I am listening for some changes and call the function "update()" to update my information:

```
function update(index) {
    var localizedInput= document.getElementById('message');
    localizedInput.value = 'myXMLString';
}
```

Changing the value is only updating the currently selected language input (with the whole XML String). The XML String is correct, but I am not sure on how to update the XML for the input with javascript.

Is this possible?

PS: I have posted this in the [Liferay Dev forum](https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/119753846) to try and reach more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of studying the case and some tests, I think that I found a workaround for this. Not sure if this is the correct approach, but it is working for me so I will post my current solution for future reference.

After inspecting the HTML, I noticed that the **Liferay-UI:input-localized** tag creates an **input** tag by default, and then one more input tag for each language, each time you select a new language. Knowing that I created some functions with Javascript to help me update the inputs created from my liferay-ui:input-localized. Here is the relevant code:

```
function updateAnnouncementInformation(index) {
    var announcement = announcements[index];

    // the announcement['message'] is a XML String
    updateInputLocalized('message', announcement['message']);
}

function updateInputLocalized(input, message) {
    var inputId = '<portlet:namespace/>' + input;
    var xml = $.parseXML(message);
    
    var inputCurrent = document.getElementById(inputId);
    var selectedLanguage = getSelectedLanguage(inputId);
    
    var inputPT = document.getElementById(inputId + '_pt_PT');
    inputPT.value = $(xml).find("Title[language-id='pt_PT']").text();
    
    var inputEN = document.getElementById(inputId + '_en_US');
    if (inputEN !== null) inputEN.value = $(xml).find("Title[language-id='en_US']").text();
    else waitForElement(inputId + '_en_US', inputCurrent, inputId, xml);
    
    var inputLabel = getInputLabel(inputId);
    if (selectedLanguage == 'pt-PT') inputLabel.innerHTML = '';
    else inputLabel.innerHTML = inputPT.value;
    
    if (selectedLanguage == 'pt-PT') inputCurrent.value = inputPT.value;
    else if (inputEN !== null) inputCurrent.value = inputEN.value;
    else waitForElement(inputId + '_en_US', inputCurrent, inputId, xml);
}

function getSelectedLanguage(inputId) {
    var languageContainer = document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace/>' + inputId + 'Menu');
    return languageContainer.getElementsByClassName('btn-section')[0].innerHTML;
}

function getInputLabel(inputId) {
    var boundingBoxContainer = document.getElementById(inputId + 'BoundingBox').parentElement;
    return boundingBoxContainer.getElementsByClassName('form-text')[0];
}

function waitForElement(elementId, inputCurrent, inputId, xml) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (element) elementCreated(element, inputCurrent, inputId, xml);
        else waitForElement(elementId, inputCurrent, inputId, xml);
    }, 500);
}

function elementCreated(inputEN, inputCurrent, inputId, xml) {
    inputEN.value = $(xml).find("Title[language-id='en_US']").text();
    
    var selectedLanguage = getSelectedLanguage(inputId);
    if (selectedLanguage == 'en-US') inputCurrent.value = inputEN.value;
}
```

With this I am able to update the **liferay-ui:input-localized** inputs according to a pre-built XML String. I hope that someone finds this useful and if you have anything to add, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

To change the text value of an element, you must change the value of the elements's text node.

Example -

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "new content"
```

Suppose "books.xml" is loaded into xmlDoc

Get the first child node of the  element

Change the node value to "new content"

Comment: I do not know why you voted down my answer. If I did comment something wrong because I did not understand the question then you can first tell me in the comment so that I can learn what I did wrong.

Comment: My question is not how to change XML object values. Instead is how to change the value of the tag liferay-ui:input-localized based on a pre-build XML String